# ModelBuilder using iterator as precondition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, iterator, precondition

Was wondering how I can iterate over field values and when all the iteration is done to move onto the group at the end. I've tried setting a precondition within the loop but that just causes the whole data processing to run every loop which would cause the model to take a lot longer. I also tried making that section it's own model but there is no output so I can't set a precondition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it but create a submodel which iterates then add this submodel to your main model:

> All tools that need to run multiple times should be placed in one
> model with a model iterator and used as a submodel. The tools that
> only need to be run once should be placed in the main model, which
> calls the iterating submodel.

See: [Advanced use of model iterators](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/add-a-submodel-to-a-model.htm)

Comment: OK, yeah I needed to make the output a parameter to get it to show up as a submodel. Now my problem is the data processing after. It is all just messed up when it worked perfectly on the table beforehand. It seems to just randomly process some rows but not others. Is there something else I needed to do?

Comment: The errors I get are: 002116: Unable to convert all the values from LMT_Date to DateString, but it doesn't say why. Also warnings like 002858: Certain rows set to NULL due to error while evaluating python expression, but the python expression worked perfectly when running it on the table before I started deleting rows.